# Squid - Whitelist a perticular Git Repo

Tags: proxy, squid, whitelist

This is how my proxy_whitelist.config file looks like;

```
.ubuntu.com
.redhat.com
```

It is working fine.

I need to allow my users access to a perticular `Git Repo`.

I tried the following

`.github.com/jquery/jquery` did not work.
`.github.com` worked but too open.

Is there a way i can add perticular URL and only allow access to that URL?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to use an acl of type regular expression, check this link for more details, check out "Type of acl" section. http://www.deckle.co.uk/squid-users-guide/squid-access-control-and-access-control-operators.html

Comment: Also make sure you are doing SSL bump if you need to allow HTTPS URLs. Otherwise your proxy just sees "CONNECT github.com:443" which obviously does not contain the specific repo URL.